# How do I obtain a list of audio formats that the current browser can decode via the web audio API?

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm using the web audio javascript API? If I loop through several popular audio formats, and then call `document.getElementById('someAudioTag').canPlayType('audio/ogg');` for each format (in this case, ogg), do I get a list of audio formats that I can feed into decodeAudioData?

Is there a more straightforward method to get the list of supported formats via the web audio API?

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much the only way, I think, aside from incorporating a table like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) (note that that's the formats supported by `<audio>` and `<video>` tags, which is not quite the same as supported by the Web Audio API; for example IE doesn't have Web Audio at all yet).

You're likely to get a result of "maybe" on a lot of formats, at least if you don't specify a codec (and I haven't figured out exactly how to specify a codec yet-- I hope someone else can chime in).

Answer (score 2):

WebAudio does not provide any way to determine what formats are supported by decodeAudioData.